# FabricJS opacity issues on render

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to render this picture on my canvas:

[image: test image]

But this is how it renders with FabricJS:

[image: FabricJS]

By the way, with EaselJS the same picture renders normally

[image: EaselJS]

My CoffeeScript:

```
renderPicture = (pic) ->
  pic.left = coords.x - (pic.width / 2)
  pic.top = coords.y - (pic.height / 2)
  canvas.add(pic)

image = new fabric.Image.fromURL '/images/medium/missing.png', renderPicture, {
  opacity: 1
}
```

As you can see, opacity of the picture equals 1, but I still see it as opacity was 0.5. How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in hardcoded opacity in my HTML.

```
<canvas id="editorWindow" style="background-color: rgba(255, 194, 93, 0.4)">
</canvas>
```

CreateJS ignored that, but for FabricJS it's critical. You should change bg color using [buitl-in function](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#backgroundColor) instead.